# Prevent Excel custom function running on file open

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am building an Excel add-in with many custom functions. They work fine, however, when I close and reopen the file, all functions are recalculated. Since each custom function makes an API request to my website and the data does not change frequently, I am looking for a way to turn this feature off so that functions do no rerun on file open. I have looked through all the docs but could not find any answers. Really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

My add-in will be used by other users so I am looking for a solution that does not require any extra action from the (like setting the calculation mode of the spreadsheet to manual)

Comment: set calculation to manual?.....

Comment: other users will be using my add-in so I am looking for a solution that doesn't require any action from them. I will modify the question.

Comment: Under what set of conditions or with what frequency are you expecting the functions to recalculate?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the manual calculation in the following way:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
```

The [XlCalculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation) enumeration specifies the calculation mode.